# Python Tkinter label entry Widget spacing issue

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout, tkinter-layout

I am new to Tkinter and I'm having some issues with Tkinter label and entry widget for displaying information. I am able to get the row position correct but the column positions for my entry widget is messed up.

1. I am placing the entry on the next to label but there seems to lots of gap between label and entry.
2. All my labels starts from same column position their orientation on different rows are slights off. Not very smooth alignment.

**Tried column span , grid_columnconfigure, sticky**

```
from Tkinter import *  
app = Tk()

app.title('Customer Information')

cidText=StringVar()
cidText.set("Customer ID")
labelCID=Label(app, textvariable=cidText, height=3)

cidValue=StringVar(app,value='1001')
cidEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=cidValue,width=4)
labelCID.grid(row=1,column=5)
cidEntry.grid(row=1,column=6)

labelText=StringVar()
labelText.set("First Name")
labelfname=Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=2)
labelfname.grid(row=2,column=5)

fvalue=StringVar(app,value='Jill')
fentry=Entry(app,textvariable=fvalue,width=10)
fentry.grid(row=2,column=6)

lnameText=StringVar()
lnameText.set("last Name")
labelLname=Label(app, textvariable=lnameText, height=2)
labelLname.grid(row=2,column=7)

#lnameValue=StringVar(None)
lnameValue=StringVar(app,value='Miller')
lnameEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=lnameValue,width=20)
lnameEntry.grid(row=2,column=8)

strNameText=StringVar()
strNameText.set("Street Address")
labelStrName=Label(app, textvariable=strNameText, height=2)
labelStrName.grid(row=3,column=5,sticky=E)
strValue=StringVar(app,value='38 Main Street')
strEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=strValue,width=20)
strEntry.grid(row=3,column=6)

cityText=StringVar()
cityText.set("City")
labelCity=Label(app, textvariable=cityText, height=2)
labelCity.grid(row=3,column=7)

cityValue=StringVar(app,value='New York')
cityEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=cityValue,width=20)
cityEntry.grid(row=3,column=8)

stateText=StringVar()
stateText.set("State")
labelState=Label(app, textvariable=stateText, height=2)
labelState.grid(row=3,column=9)

stateValue=StringVar(app,value='NY')
stateEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=stateValue,width=2)
stateEntry.grid(row=3,column=10)

zipText=StringVar()
zipText.set("Zip")
labelzip=Label(app, textvariable=zipText, height=2)
labelzip.grid(row=3,column=11)

zipValue=StringVar(app,value='12345')
zipEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=zipValue,width=5)
zipEntry.grid(row=3,column=12)


Button(app, text='Quit', command=app.quit).grid(row=10, column=5, sticky=W)

zipText=StringVar()
zipText.set(" ")
labelzip=Label(app, textvariable=zipText, height=4)
labelzip.grid(row=15,column=11)

app.grid_columnconfigure(4, minsize=100)

app.mainloop()
```

There is lots of gap between some label and entry on the form.
I want to have the labels and entry next to each other without much spaces

Comment: As it's not clear from *"labels and entry next to each other without much spaces"* add a link to a **screenshoot**. Read about [Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method)

Comment: I was able to find workaround for this. By  keeping the same value for width for all entry widgets that are in same column. for example ,:

CustomerIDEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=cidValue,width=20)
fnameEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=fvalue,width=20)
streetNameEntry=Entry(app,textvariable=strValue,width=20)

This makes all these entries to 20 spaces width. don't need that kind of spaces for Customer ID field. 
I know not the best approach but for time being working with it.